# Extract value from bash array with a delimiter

Tags: bash

I have an array
`my_array=(foo:123 bar:456 baz:789 lorem:012 ipsum:345)`

I want to extract the value after delimiter for a given key

eg. passing `foo` should return 123. Similarly, passing `lorem` should return 012

Comment: Why don't you `typeset -A my_array=(foo 123 bar 456 baz 789 lorem 012 ipsum 345)` and then use `${my_array[foo]}` and `${my_array[lorem]}`?

Comment: @accdias Not working with bash-4. Does it work with bash-5?

Comment: `declare -A my_array=([foo]=123 [bar]=456 [baz]=789 [lorem]=012); echo "${my_array[foo]}"` , look for _associative array_

Comment: @Fravadona, I don't remember when that syntax for associative arrays were introduced in Bash, but I'm using version `5.1.16(1)-release`.

Comment: `bash4+` according to this [wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061)

Comment: @Fravadona that new type of key-val assignment was added in 5.1 according to https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is acceptable to prepare another (associative) array variable, how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_array=(foo:123 bar:456 baz:789 lorem:012 ipsum:345)
declare -A $(printf "%s\n" "${my_array[@]}" | sed 's/\(.*\):\(.*\)/my_array2[\1]=\2/')

declare -p my_array2
```

Output:

```
declare -A my_array2=([bar]="456" [baz]="789" [foo]="123" [lorem]="012" [ipsum]="345" )
```

Then `echo "${my_array2[foo]}"` will output `123` as an example.

Please note passing variables or command outputs to `declare` has a possible
vulnerability risk. Make sure the strings in `my_array` are fully under control.

Comment: Is there a way to generate the associative array dynamically? I have an array of users (foo bar baz). The values should come from output of `openssl rand -hex 36`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. One question: how do you run the `openssl`
command with the user name? My assumption is something like
`num=$(openssl <options> "$user")`, where "$user" is a user name such as "foo"
and the output is "123" which "num" is assigned to. Am I correct?

Comment: user will be the key eg. "foo" and the value is a random string from the output of `openssl rand -hex 36`. Resulting associative array is like - `my_array=([foo]="e8db7...d7123" [baz]="4fb67....cfcb"`

Comment: I'm afraid it is still unclear.
Is the user such as `foo` is included in the `openssl`
command arguments? If not, I don't get the meaning of `dynamically`
because the user and the (random) value are then logically unrelated
and they don't have to be dynamically generated. Or the user is
added on the fly (dynamically) during the execution?

Comment: I solved it :) I think you'll be able to understand better from code. First, we have a users array `users=(foo bar baz)`. Second, create an associative array `declare -A users_with_password`. Third, `for user in ${users[@]}; do users_with_password["$user"]="$(openssl rand -hex 36)"; done`

Comment: I've totally understood what you want to do and your code is very clear. Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to access a few keys then you could use a parameter expansion that strips everything but the value of interest from the bash array:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

my_array=(foo:123 bar:456 baz:789 lorem:012 ipsum:345)

my_key=lorem
my_val=${my_array[@]/@("$my_key":|!("$my_key":*))/}

echo "$my_val"
```

<sup>**note:** leading and trailing blanks will be stripped from `my_val`</sup>

```
012
```

If you'll be accessing a lot of keys then the previous method is too inefficient so you'll need to build an associative array (bash 4+):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

my_array=(foo:123 bar:456 baz:789 lorem:012 ipsum:345)

declare -A my_hash
for elem in "${my_array[@]}"
do
    IFS=':' read -r key val <<< "$elem"
    my_hash["$key"]=$val
done

echo "${my_hash[lorem]}"
```

```
012
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using older bash versions where associative arrays are not available you could use bash regex matching and parameter substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern=${1:-lorem}

arr=(foo:123 bar:456 baz:789 lorem:012 ipsum:345)

for i in "${arr[@]}" ; do
    if [[ "${i}" =~ ^${pattern}:* ]] ; then
        echo "${i##*:}"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./foo.sh   # default pattern is lorem
012
$ ./script foo
123
$ ./script bar
456
$ ./script baz
789
$ ./script lorem
012
$ ./script ipsum
345
```